# FSCalendar library selected Date Circle size issue

Tags: swift

1. How we can increase the size of the selected date title circle in FSCalendar library[as we can see in the image I want the circle bigger than current size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IROlr.png)

calendar.appearance.borderRadius = .someValue // I tried all Value of enum But it not works

Comment: Probably you can't check the Pod has 360+ open issues. btw, edit and add what you are trying to do in code and what problem it throws at you, you should try it before asking.

Answer (score 2):

Override FSCalendarCell layoutSubviews method.

Here is my code.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    
    let titleHeight: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.height * 4.1 / 5
    var diameter: CGFloat = min(self.bounds.size.height * 5.2 / 8, self.bounds.size.width)
    diameter = diameter > FSCalendarStandardCellDiameter ? (diameter - (diameter-FSCalendarStandardCellDiameter) * 0.5) : diameter
    shapeLayer.frame = CGRect(x: (bounds.size.width - diameter) / 2,
                              y: (titleHeight - diameter) / 2,
                              width: diameter, height: diameter)
    
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shapeLayer.bounds, cornerRadius: shapeLayer.bounds.width * 0.5 * appearance.borderRadius).cgPath
    if shapeLayer.path != path {
        shapeLayer.path = path
    }
}
```

Change the value titleHeight, diameter to increase/decrease the size of selected date circle.